# g++ bug? (bool_val ? 0 : 1) returns neither 0 nor 1

Tags: c++, gcc

I reproduce the problem by this simple demo:

```
// bool_test_func.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void func(bool* b) {
  int a = (*b ? 0 : 1);
  printf("%d\n", a); // EXPECT ether 0 or 1 here
}

// bool_test.cpp
void func(bool* b);

int main() {
  int n = 128;
  func((bool*)&n);
  return 0;
}
```

-O0 compile and run:

```
g++ -g -O0 -Wall -o bool_test bool_test.cpp bool_test_func.cpp
mikewei@maclinux:~/testing/c++$ ./bool_test
0
```

-O1 compile and run (unexpected result):

```
g++ -g -O1 -Wall -o bool_test bool_test.cpp bool_test_func.cpp
mikewei@maclinux:~/testing/c++$ ./bool_test
129
```

When I check the -O2 ASM code, I think it is a g++ bug, g++'s optimzation code always think the bool value is ether 1 or 0:

```
    00000000004005e6 :
      4005e6:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
      4005ea:       0f b6 37                movzbl (%rdi),%esi
      4005ed:       83 f6 01                xor    $0x1,%esi  #just XOR the bool val
      4005f0:       40 0f b6 f6             movzbl %sil,%esi
      4005f4:       bf 94 06 40 00          mov    $0x400694,%edi
      4005f9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
      4005fe:       e8 9d fe ff ff          callq  4004a0 
      400603:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
      400607:       c3                      retq
      400608:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
      40060f:       00
```

gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Is this g++ behavior by design? How can I disable this wrong optimaztion?
Thanks~

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Comment: Interesting `#include`.

Comment: The optimization is not wrong : a bool can only contain 0 or 1. What you're passing in is an `int` type-punned as a `bool`, undefined behaviour ensues.

Comment: Rather bold statement that this is a gcc bug...

Comment: Not sure I agree with the dupe close reason, supposed original is actually due to uninitialised variable, nothing to do with ub caused by type punning.

Comment: Not sure whether I up-vote this for being a good example of UB or down-vote for UB and arrogance over this "wrong optimization", and the use of C headers and casts?

Comment: @djgandy, vote the question, not the asker :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo different cause, same symptom : the compiler assumes that the boolean is valid when it's not, and prints it out unmodified.

Comment: `-Dbool=int` is an option that "disables this optimization"...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> I think it is a g++ bug.

Have to respectfully disagree there.

> How can I disable this wrong optimisation?

Even if that *is* possible, it's not *actually* wrong :-)

You are passing a non-bool pointer as a bool pointer (the underlying item is not of the bool type) and I'm pretty certain that this (known as type punning) invokes undefined behaviour.

Hence the code is free to do whatever it wants.

You can think of the prototype `void func(bool* b)` as a *contract* you agree to to only ever pass pointers to `bool` values. If you violate that contract, all bets are off. In this particular case, your code:

```
int a = (*b ? 0 : 1);
```

is telling it to convert false to 1 and true to 0. If you were to supply *valid* input (`false/0` or `true/1`), the `xor input, 1` would be *exactly* the right thing to do.

However, because you're giving it `128`, the `xor` results in `129`.

Comment: Agreed. The implementation appears to implement a bool with values 0 and 1. Therefore as long as bool types are only ever used, they can be easily manipulated with xor. Also conversion to int is easy, as the underlying bool appears to be an int, so there is no conversion operation necessary.

Comment: This is called type punning, and the standard forbids type punning from int to bool (§3.10/10 in N3376). It is indeed UB.

Comment: The final part of the question is how to disable the optimization. While I would strongly advise against doing so and disagree with the questioner's description of it as a "wrong optimization", there are named optimizations that gcc allows you to disable in order to write code that has UB according to the standard. `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` is a famous example. I haven't checked but does `-fno-strict-aliasing` "fix" this code?

Comment: Ah, I guess not, since `-O1` doesn't include `-fstrict-aliasing`. Still, if this is due to a named optimization, then information about it would enhance this answer a little.

Comment: Interesting choice. I wonder how much worse it is to consider a 0/non-0 type of boolean rather than the strict 0/1 kind like in this case. AFAIK, Microsoft went with the former model for `cl`.